# Custom view in multi-selected lookup - CRM Online upgrade

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

We were using below code that works fine in MSCRM online 2011 online to show custom view in multi-selected lookup dialog page on click of Add Existing Records ribbon button in subgrid of associated entity.

```js
function addExistingFromSubGridQuoteProducts(gridTypeCode, gridControl, shipmentID) {

    var entity = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();

    var QuoteAttribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_quoteid");

    if (QuoteAttribute == null) {

       QuoteAttribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_quote");

    }

    var Quote = QuoteAttribute.getValue();

    var Quoteid = "Unknown";

    if (Quote != null) {

       Quoteid = Quote[0].id;

    }

    var filter =  "<filter type='and'>"

               + "<condition attribute='new_quoteshipmentid' operator='null' />"

               + "</filter>"

    var fxml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"

     + "<entity name='quotedetail'>"

       + "<attribute name='productid' />"

       + "<attribute name='productdescription' />"

       + "<attribute name='priceperunit' />"

       + "<attribute name='quantity' />"

       + "<attribute name='extendedamount' />"

       + "<attribute name='quotedetailid' />"

       + "<order attribute='productid' descending='false' />"

       + filter

       + "<link-entity name='quote' from='quoteid' to='quoteid' alias='aa'>"

         + "<filter type='and'>"

           + "<condition attribute='quoteid' operator='eq' value='" + Quoteid + "' />"

         + "</filter>"

       + "</link-entity>"

     + "</entity>"

   + "</fetch>";

   addExistingFromSubGridCustom({

       entityName: entity,

       gridTypeCode: gridTypeCode,

       gridControl: gridControl,

       fetchXml: fxml,

       layoutXml: "<grid name='resultset' " +

                        "object='1' " +

                        "jump='productid' " +

                        "select='1' " +

                        "icon='1' " +

                        "preview='1'>" +

                    "<row name='result' " + "id='quotedetailid'>" +

                      "<cell name='productid' width='300' />" +

                      "<cell name='productdescription' width='300' />" +

                    "</row>" +

                  "</grid>"

   });

}

function addExistingFromSubGridCustom(params) {

viewId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}";

var customView = {

   fetchXml: params.fetchXml,

   id: viewId,

   layoutXml: params.layoutXml,

   name: "Filtered Lookup View",

   recordType: params.gridTypeCode,

   Type: 0

};

var lookupItems = LookupObjects(null, "multi", params.gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);

if (lookupItems && lookupItems.items.length > 0) {

   for (var i = 0; i< lookupItems.items.length; i++){

       var lhsEntityId;

       var lhsSet;

       var relatedEntityId;

       var relatedEntitySet = "";

       var relationName = "";

       lhsEntityId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

       lhsSet = "new_quoteshipmentSet";

       relatedEntityId = lookupItems.items[i].id;

       relatedEntitySet = "QuoteDetailSet";

       relationName = "new_quoteshipment_quotedetail";

       var done = XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Associate(

               lhsEntityId,

               lhsSet,

               relatedEntityId,

               relatedEntitySet,

               relationName,

               function () {

                   var i = 0;

               },

               function (error) {

                   var i = 0;

               },

               false

       );

    }

    params.gridControl.refresh();

    }

}
```

But after upgrade to MSCRM 2013, This code shows multi-selected lookup with custom view selected in viewpicker but throws following error:

> “The requested record was not found or you do not have permissions to
>   view.”

On click of show error logs in error window, following error detail was shown:

> “savedquery With Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Does Not
>   Exist.”

On debugging of above javascript code, I found that the error is thrown by following line of code:

```js
   var lookupItems = LookupObjects(null, "multi", params.gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);
```

Could someone please help me in fixing of this error due to LookupObjects JavaScript method in MSCRM 2013 online.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `LookupObjectsWithCallback` since `LookupObjects` doesn't return a value

```
LookupObjectsWithCallback(callbackReference,null, "multi", params.gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]););
```

where

```
callbackReference={callback:function (lookupItems){
        //Do Something
    }
}
```